# 'Certificate' Option missing from Windows 10 Enterprise VPN connection properties

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, azure-vpn

When trying to connect to an Azure VPN, I noticed that the 'Certificate' option is missing from my version of Windows 10 when I try to edit the VPN connection properties. The only options listed are 'Username and password', 'Smart card' and 'One-time password'.

How would I go about getting the certificate option added?

Windows version:
Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB
Version 10.0.10240 Build 10240

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you use a point to site VPN? If so, there is a `Generic` folder in the downloaded VPN client package. If So, do you see the `VpnServerRoot` certificate in this folder?

Comment: @NancyXiong Yes I do see that file. But I'm not using Generic. I'm using the "WindowsAmd64" one. Are you saying I can use Generic instead somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this particular version of Windows 10 doesn't have that option. I got around this by upgrading to the 2016 LTSB version and the Certificate option appeared.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to **download and install the latest Windows updates** in my case this was:

> Windows 10 version 1809 - [Windows 10 May 2019 Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-update)

This espesially important in your in place upgrade or new install was from a local media and you did not select download latest updates during the Windows 10 installation process.